# Discrepancy between line integral over scalar field and line integral over vector field

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

There is a discrepancy between the line integral over a scalar field and the line integral over a vector field that is bothering me:

Say $\gamma$ is a smooth curve. If $\gamma : \mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ then the line integral of a scalar field $f: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ along $\gamma$ is given by

$$ L = \int_a^b f(\gamma)|\gamma'(t)|dt $$

Let's compare this to the multidimensional equivalent. If $\gamma: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R^m$ and $f:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$ then

$$ L = \int_a^b f(\gamma(t)) \cdot \gamma'(t) dt$$

where $\cdot$ is the scalar product.

The discrepancy is the absolute value in the dimension $1$ case. I do understand how to derive each. Looking at the definition of arc length of a curve I think the $m=1$ case is pretty clear. Similarly, the meaning of the scalar product makes the higher dimensional case pretty clear, too.

But yet, it seems to me that what applies in $m$ dimensions should usually also apply in $1$ dimension. That is, the integral if $m=1$ should be

$$ L = \int_a^b f(\gamma)\gamma'(t)dt $$

In one dimension the scalar product is just multiplication.

> But why does this not apply? Why does one have to have absolute value
>   of $\gamma'$ and just $\gamma'$ does not work?

Comment: There is no discrepancy.  They mean different things.

Comment: Orientation is the reason for this. Read up about orientation of manifolds, or line integrals, and see that the absolute value must be put to preserve orientation.

Comment: First of all, $\gamma\colon\Bbb R\to\Bbb R^n$. This is a parametrized curve, after all.